# Slides don't work if a slide is wrapped within a custom component

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4, swiper.js

I want to wrap my slide component in my own component to achieve ATOM methodology. But since `ion-slide` is not a direct child of `ion-slides` anymore it doesn't detect the multiple slides.

This is my `app-slide` component:

```
<ion-slide>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ion-slide>
```

Then I call it like this:

```
<ion-slides>
  <app-slide>Test</app-slide>
  <app-slide>Test 2</app-slide>
  <app-slide>Test 3</app-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-x7wgrz

Is there a way to ignore the parent? Or how else could I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using the class `swiper-slide` as it is originally done in `swiperjs`.

```
<ion-slides>
  <app-slide class="swiper-slide">Test</app-slide>
  <app-slide class="swiper-slide">Test 2</app-slide>
  <app-slide class="swiper-slide">Test 3</app-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

An even better solution in order to not manually type the class everytime is adding a `HostBinding` to the `app-slide` component like so:

```
@HostBinding('class.swiper-slide') swiperSlide: boolean = true;
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-x7wgrz

Answer (score 2):

You just need some changes to your structure. Please give a try to the below code.

Here is the working code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-zwjta3

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
        <app-slide>Test</app-slide>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <app-slide>Test 2</app-slide>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <app-slide>Test 3</app-slide>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Your component file should look like below.

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: This means I have to use `ion-slide` everytime I want to use `app-slide`. It isn't what I'm looking for. I want it to replace `ion-slide`. I would rather just use `ion-slide` instead of my own component in this case.